# How to open Other app from ReactNative?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

How to open other apps (Gmail, Camera) from ReactNative. How can I pass data from current scene to other app?

Answer (score 1):

I found this npm library **react-native-app-link** which can open other apps. This is based on deep linking, if you have any deep links then this library can help.  This doesn't open apps just by giving the android package name or ios app id.

https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link

Comment: Is there any other way to open `the app` without `deep link URL`?

Answer (score 0):

you can mange opening other apps using [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html)

Comment: const googlePlayLink = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en'
    
const app = 'whatsapp://app'

    Linking.openURL(app).catch(err => {
      console.log('whatsapp is not installed', err)
      Linking.openURL(googlePlayLink)
    })

Comment: Is there any other way to open `the app` without a `deep link URL`?

Answer (score 0):

Code sample for opening the dialer

```
const urlToOpen = 'tel:1234567890';
Linking.openURL(urlToOpen);
```

You can refer to [the official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) here, it just predefines some applications, which can be opened.

However, if the question is about to open just about any application, I hope there is no solution till now.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-app-link` has some redundant config (e.g. `appStoreLocale` parameter), so I wrote my own realization using their code:

```js
import { Alert, Platform, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';

const isIos = Platform.OS === 'ios';

const showNotification = (text) => isIos
  ? Alert.alert(text)
  : ToastAndroid.show(text, ToastAndroid.SHORT);

const openApp = ({ url, appStoreId, playMarketId, name }) => {
  Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => {
    if (err.code === 'EUNSPECIFIED') {
      Linking.openURL(
        isIos
          ? `https://apps.apple.com/app/id${appStoreId}`
          : `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${playMarketId}`,
      );
    } else {
      showNotification(`Can't open ${name} app`);
    }
  });
};
```

It tries to open the app by the specified link, and if the user doesn't have such one, it opens its page in AppStore or Play Market.