# Is there any way I can play videos with Third-Party Video players in my mobile using React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am storing my videos in Firebase Storage. I want to give an option to play the videos i am retrieving from Firebase in a Third-Party player.

Comment: seems like a specific case of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040100/ . I think what you need is "Linking.openURL(this.state.post_url);" . Just put your video urls inside openURL

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo, yes there is:

Expo is a free and open source toolchain built around React Native to help you build native iOS and Android projects using JavaScript and React - [Expo Website](https://expo.io/)

The Expo SDK, which include components and many more cool stuff, come built-in with create-react-native-app has the [Video Component](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video.html)

It is a component that displays a video inline with the other React Native UI elements in your app. The display dimensions and position of the video on screen can be set using usual React Native styling.

You can use that to play the videos hosted on firebase