# Open email app without composing email in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Looking for a simple solution to open the default email app/client on iOS and Android from a React Native app WITHOUT popping a new email compose window?

(just open the app to see the user's inbox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536216/open-external-app-from-react-native-app ?

Comment: I don't know.. they are talking about whatsapp there. Do you know what's the correct URL scheme for android/iOS to open the email app without a active compose window?