# How to open other application from my application

Tags: ios, react-native, linker, deep-linking, deeplink

I am writing code to launch other applications from my react native application for `android` and `ios`.

Using `Linking` form react native I am able to redirect to `Play Store/App Store` but

**How can I launch App if it's already installed?**

*** I am getting the list of the app's from server**

[image]

```
Linking.openURL('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.myapp&hl=en')
```

Is there any way that I can launch the `app` if it's installed else redirect to `App store/play store` with respect to the platform?

Reference:[react-native-app-link](https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: I don't understand what you want! You want to open other apps it's already installed in your app ?

Comment: It depends upon which app you wants to open and what data you have to pass in that app.Suppose you want to open map app from your RN app .with custom latitude&longitude values.For that you can use this one                                                var scheme = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'maps:' : 'geo:';
var url = scheme + `${lat},${lng}`;
Linking.openURL(url); Import {Linking} from "react-native"

Comment: @AbdulBasit I just want to launch the app, I have app with name `Sagar` and package name `com.sagar` so how can I go for same

Comment: `Linking.canOpenURL(yourApp
    ).then(supported => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(yourApp);
      } else {
        alert("sorry invalid url");
      }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many searches I have found an alternative for `android` without `deep link URL` is to use the native module [react-native-intent-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-intent-launcher) to launch another app using `package-name`.

You can call the native function `startActivity` in `react-native` to do something with `Intent` which can only be solved with android `native code`.

Looking for `iOS` solution without `deep link URL` if any lead please update here

Once I found I will update Here

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your other app need to handle Deeplinking. If that's not already the case, have a look [here for Android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) and [here for iOS](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97).

This will allow you to have your app's own URL scheme, for example `testapp://example`

Then you can simply use the [Linking API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html), but instead of opening a HTTP URL, you can use you Deeplink URL scheme defined previously.

```
Linking.openURL('testapp://example');
```

Comment: can we access the random app if only having `app name and package name` using react-native

Comment: @Sagar, sadly you can't. It has to be a URL as you can see here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#openurl the only way to get a URL for your app is through deep linking.

Comment: is there any way to achieve with react native

Comment: Without updating the "target" app no. The only other alternative is to open the Store as you did.